# The buff/cache of memory are not the same

Tags: centos

I have three almost same host machine(names: ha-node1, ha-node2, ha-node3), they all have good hardware.

All are CentOS 7.2 1511(Core) system.

In the ha-node1:

```
[root@ha-node1 log]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G        4.5G        241G        201M        5.9G        246G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G
```

In the ha-node2:

```
[root@ha-node2 rabbitmq]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           188G        4.2G        176G        1.6G        7.7G        182G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G
```

In the ha-node3:

```
[root@ha-node3 log]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G        4.5G        246G        9.3M        368M        246G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G
```

You see, there are different between the ha-node1 or ha-node2 with the ha-node3.

The ha-node3 have a very small `shared` and `buff/cache` memory, not like ha-node1 and ha-node2.

Why this? if is somewhere goes wrong or the hardware somewhere is bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks good.

The `buffer/cache` memory reflects the experience of the running system in handling I/O requests and ability to handle future requests faster. Maybe `ha-node3` was brought up much later than the others? See [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

The `shared` memory reflects processes that use the same data (usually shared libraries or same executables), so you may have a guess looking at `ps aux` output and seeing less processes on `ha-node3`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rather be looking at:

```
total - available
```

If that was not the same for all three machines, then it might warrant further investigation. What you are seeing is simply a machine that caches a bit more disk I/O.

Comment: whats mean of the `total`?

Comment: Total is the amount of RAM installed in the machine.